# MOXy xml-transient directive does not work on Map<Range<BigDecimal>,BigDecimal>

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy, jaxb2

When I have a Map in a class

`private Map<Range<BigDecimal>, BigDecimal> ranges;`

and I use following XML mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
        xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
        package-name="package-name">
    <xml-schema element-form-default="QUALIFIED">
        <xml-ns prefix="prefix" namespace-uri="namespace-uri"/>
    </xml-schema>
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="MyJavaType" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-transient java-attribute="ranges"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

Why does **xml-transient** not work?

It fails on:

```
The class com.google.common.collect.Range requires a zero argument constructor or a specified factory method.  
Note that non-static inner classes do not have zero argument constructors and are not supported.
```

If I use List, it works.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround which can be applied is to create:

```
public class RangeWrapper {
    @Transient
    @XmlTransient
    final Map<Range<BigDecimal>, BigDecimal> ranges;
}
```

And use it in parent class as follows:

```
@Transient
@XmlTransient
private RangeWrapper ranges;
```